# Are there any hardshell covers / protectors for lenses?

Tags: lens, equipment-protection, concert

I'm a concert photographer, and I tend to end up in mosh pits quite a bit. I've mastered the art of shielding my camera from fists and beers, but I have been starting to see some wear and tear.

**Are there any hardshell protective layers or covers for lenses?**

I'd like to at least keep my lenses in a decent shape, and I figured that there had to be some sort of product out here for this. I need something that directly covers the lens while still allowing it to be usable for shooting.

If it helps, I shoot Micro Four-Thirds, and am not against paying a premium for a custom made solution.

Comment: I don't know of any hardshell protectors designed to be used while the lens is attached, but there is this reasonably well padded protector: http://www.outdoorphotogear.com/aquatech-soft-hood-collapsible-hood-for-long-lenses/  . Otherwise you are probably looking at some kind of 3D printed solution as the most cost effective way of producing one.

Comment: Just a thought,  in the past, I've seen underwater cases for SLRs that were rigid.  If you could find one for your camera/lens combo, it would give you the rigid protection you are looking for, and make the unit "beer-proof to 10 meters" as well

Answer (score 1):

We use a blimp on movie sets for sound deadening loud cameras like Nikon. Maybe you could put your gear into a padded fibreglass shell for shock protection. This guy made his out of a Pelikan™ case.

http://blog.blairbunting.com/guest-post-diy-sound-blimp-project/

Fatboy also has a solution cheaper than replacing your gear.

[fatboysoundblimp.com/gallery.htmlk description here](http://fatboysoundblimp.com/home.html)

Comment: This looks like an interesting solution, I have been looking for a lens protector as well. In my case, I work with a local youth group that likes to play a variety of - novel - sports/games that often derive from dodgeball. It's great fun and good practice but I take my glass in my hands every time...